# Set contents of CALayer to animated GIF?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

Is it possible to set the contents of a `CALayer` to an animated GIF and have it display that animation? I know that I can set the contents to an image like so:

```
CALayer* subLayer = [CALayer layer];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
subLayer.contents = image;
```

And the image will show, but if it's animated, the animation will not display. Is the only solution to get the individual frames for the GIF, get the frame rate, then change the `content` of the sublayer according to the frame rate? Or is there a much simpler method that I'm overlooking?

Comment: You can animate the `contents` of the layer but you still have to get all the individual frames. (by "you can animate" I mean: "you can use a CAKeyframeAnimation")

Comment: its unclear why you are trying to do this with `CALayer`. if you only goal is to show an animated GIFthere are better ways.

Comment: @BradAllred I'm loading a fair number of images into `CALayer`s and then individually showing one at a time, but sometimes the images are GIFs. I would normally just use an `NSImageView`, but the performance was awful compared to Core Animation. I suppose if the loaded image is a GIF, I could use an `NSImageView` overlay with the GIF?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Does that seem like overkill?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, okay, I guess this isn't that hard to do. Basically I check to see if the image is a GIF:

```
if ([format isEqualToString:@"gif"]){
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [self createGIFAnimation:data];
    [subLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];
}
```

And as you can see, I'm calling my custom `createGIFAnimation` method, which looks like this:

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)createGIFAnimation:(NSData *)data{
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:data];
    CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)(data), nil);
    NSNumber *frameCount = [rep valueForProperty:@"NSImageFrameCount"];

    // Total loop time
    float time = 0;

    // Arrays
    NSMutableArray *framesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *tempTimesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount.intValue; i++){

        // Frame default duration
        float frameDuration = 0.1f;

        // Frame duration
        CFDictionaryRef cfFrameProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(src,i,nil);
        NSDictionary *frameProperties = (__bridge NSDictionary*)cfFrameProperties;
        NSDictionary *gifProperties = frameProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

        // Use kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime or kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime
        NSNumber *delayTimeUnclampedProp = gifProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime];
        if(delayTimeUnclampedProp) {
            frameDuration = [delayTimeUnclampedProp floatValue];
        } else {
            NSNumber *delayTimeProp = gifProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];
            if(delayTimeProp) {
                frameDuration = [delayTimeProp floatValue];
            }
        }

        // Make sure its not too small
        if (frameDuration < 0.011f){
            frameDuration = 0.100f;
        }

        [tempTimesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:frameDuration]];

        // Release
        CFRelease(cfFrameProperties);

        // Add frame to array of frames
        CGImageRef frame = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, i, nil);
        [framesArray addObject:(__bridge id)(frame)];

        // Compile total loop time
        time = time + frameDuration;
    }

    NSMutableArray *timesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    float base = 0;
    for (NSNumber* duration in tempTimesArray){
        //duration = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(duration.floatValue/time) + base];
        base = base + (duration.floatValue/time);
        [timesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:base]];
    }

    // Create animation
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];

    animation.duration = time;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.values = framesArray;
    animation.keyTimes = timesArray;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;

    return animation;
}
```

Pretty straightforward, although I would love some tips on how to improve it.

Comment: Just added a minor improvement by replacing NSBitmapImageRep with CGImageSourceGetCount and added the arrayWithCapacity hints.

Comment: @mahaltertin Thanks for the suggestions. Instead of updating the post, it'd be better to either post a new answer with the improved code, or positing a comment outlining your improvements.

Comment: size_t frameCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(src);  // instead of line 2 and 4

Comment: [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frameCount] // hint when creating the mutable arrays

Comment: Above as requested the improvement. You may add those to your post if you like.

Comment: Need to add [timesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]]; after times for loop as when kCAAnimationDiscrete is used for calculation value time array must have one more entry and should always end with 1.0. For when last frame of gif was not being played and after adding it all is good.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3** version, but changed to receive URL (for my own purpose).

```
func createGIFAnimation(url:URL) -> CAKeyframeAnimation?{

    guard let src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else { return nil }
    let frameCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(src)

    // Total loop time
    var time : Float = 0

    // Arrays
    var framesArray = [AnyObject]()
    var tempTimesArray = [NSNumber]()

    // Loop
    for i in 0..<frameCount {

        // Frame default duration
        var frameDuration : Float = 0.1;

        let cfFrameProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(src, i, nil)
        guard let framePrpoerties = cfFrameProperties as? [String:AnyObject] else {return nil}
        guard let gifProperties = framePrpoerties[kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String] as? [String:AnyObject]
            else { return nil }

        // Use kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime or kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime
        if let delayTimeUnclampedProp = gifProperties[kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime as String] as? NSNumber {
            frameDuration = delayTimeUnclampedProp.floatValue
        }
        else{
            if let delayTimeProp = gifProperties[kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String] as? NSNumber {
                frameDuration = delayTimeProp.floatValue
            }
        }

        // Make sure its not too small
        if frameDuration < 0.011 {
            frameDuration = 0.100;
        }

        // Add frame to array of frames
        if let frame = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, i, nil) {
            tempTimesArray.append(NSNumber(value: frameDuration))
            framesArray.append(frame)
        }

        // Compile total loop time
        time = time + frameDuration
    }

    var timesArray = [NSNumber]()
    var base : Float = 0
    for duration in tempTimesArray {
        timesArray.append(NSNumber(value: base))
        base.add( duration.floatValue / time )
    }

    // From documentation of 'CAKeyframeAnimation':
    // the first value in the array must be 0.0 and the last value must be 1.0.
    // The array should have one more entry than appears in the values array.
    // For example, if there are two values, there should be three key times.
    timesArray.append(NSNumber(value: 1.0))

    // Create animation
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "contents")

    animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
    animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(time)
    animation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude;
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.values = framesArray
    animation.keyTimes = timesArray
    //animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete

    return animation;
}
```

Important thing is written in the documentation of 'CAKeyframeAnimation':

> the first value in the array must be 0.0 and the last value must be 1.0.
>   The array should have one more entry than appears in the values array.
>   For example, if there are two values, there should be three key times.

So added this line:

```
 timesArray.append(NSNumber(value: 1.0))
```

And also checked in exporting as video with AVAssetExportSession.

Please call like this:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "animation", withExtension: "gif"){
    let animation = createGIFAnimation(url: url)
}
```

Comment: I have a gif image in my resource folder. How to load it using the above code? Do i need to send the bundle url of the gif image to this method?

Comment: I know this is old but what if you want a custom repeat count, say repeat the gif 2 or 3 times? Any value other than infinite causes the gif not to play.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)createGIFAnimation:(NSData *)data{

    CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)(data), nil);
    int frameCount =(int) CGImageSourceGetCount(src);

    // Total loop time
    float time = 0;

    // Arrays
    NSMutableArray *framesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *tempTimesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){

        // Frame default duration
        float frameDuration = 0.1f;

        // Frame duration
        CFDictionaryRef cfFrameProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(src,i,nil);
        NSDictionary *frameProperties = (__bridge NSDictionary*)cfFrameProperties;
        NSDictionary *gifProperties = frameProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

        // Use kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime or kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime
        NSNumber *delayTimeUnclampedProp = gifProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime];
        if(delayTimeUnclampedProp) {
            frameDuration = [delayTimeUnclampedProp floatValue];
        } else {
            NSNumber *delayTimeProp = gifProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];
            if(delayTimeProp) {
                frameDuration = [delayTimeProp floatValue];
            }
        }

        // Make sure its not too small
        if (frameDuration < 0.011f){
            frameDuration = 0.100f;
        }

        [tempTimesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:frameDuration]];

        // Release
        CFRelease(cfFrameProperties);

        // Add frame to array of frames
        CGImageRef frame = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, i, nil);
        [framesArray addObject:(__bridge id)(frame)];

        // Compile total loop time
        time = time + frameDuration;
    }

    NSMutableArray *timesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    float base = 0;
    for (NSNumber* duration in tempTimesArray){
        //duration = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(duration.floatValue/time) + base];
        base = base + (duration.floatValue/time);
        [timesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:base]];
    }

    // Create animation
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];

    animation.duration = time;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.values = framesArray;
    animation.keyTimes = timesArray;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;

    return animation;
}
```

according to mahal its should be done

Comment: Thanks for the sample code.  And I found two leaks in it. `src` and `frame` should be `CFRelease()`