# ARKit – Loading GIF image in SCNNode using CALayer not rendering properly

Tags: swift, ios11, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am working on an AR application in which I am rendering a 3D model.

Upon tapping a child node I am displaying a GIF image by creating animation using **CALayer** and loading it in **diffuse.contents** by following this thread [Set contents of CALayer to animated GIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125701/set-contents-of-calayer-to-animated-gif/41646638#41646638)

```
let animation : CAKeyframeAnimation = createGIFAnimation(url: gifImageURL!)!
let layer = CALayer()
layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:600, height:200)
layer.add(animation, forKey: "contents")

let newMaterial = SCNMaterial()
newMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
newMaterial.diffuse.contents = layer
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 5, height: 5)
plane.materials = [newMaterial]
let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

I am able to render the gif image in SCNNode but it is displaying only quarter of it (right bottom most portion of GIF is only visible). I tried below steps to rectify this but still in vain.

1. Changing Plane's width/height
2. Changing the bounds of CALayer
3. Tried with different sizes of gif image

Anyone please help me how to render a full gif image in SCNPlane using CALayer.

Comment: half of the image or a quarter of the image?  Because a quarter of an image sounds like it is an anchorpoint / origin issue

Comment: Yes only quarter of the image is visible. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround I followed the below procedure to load the GIF properly:

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 2, height: 2)

let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "engine", withExtension: "gif")
let animation : CAKeyframeAnimation = createGIFAnimation(url: bundleURL!)!
let layer = CALayer()
layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 900)

layer.add(animation, forKey: "contents")
let tempView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 900))
tempView.layer.bounds = CGRect(x: -450, y: -450, width: tempView.frame.size.width, height: tempView.frame.size.height)
tempView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

let newMaterial = SCNMaterial()
newMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
newMaterial.diffuse.contents = tempView.layer
plane.materials = [newMaterial]
let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
node.name = "engineGif"
let gifImagePosition = SCNVector3Make((self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].position.x)! + 2, 
                                      (self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].position.y)! + 4, 
                                      (self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].position.z)! - 2)
node.position = gifImagePosition
self.virtualObjectInteraction.selectedObject?.childNodes[0].addChildNode(node)
```

Where createGIFAnimation creates the required animation,

```
func createGIFAnimation(url:URL) -> CAKeyframeAnimation? {

    guard let src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else { return nil }
    let frameCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(src)

    // Total loop time
    var time : Float = 0

    // Arrays
    var framesArray = [AnyObject]()
    var tempTimesArray = [NSNumber]()

    // Loop
    for i in 0..<frameCount {

        // Frame default duration
        var frameDuration : Float = 0.1;

        let cfFrameProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(src, i, nil)
        guard let framePrpoerties = cfFrameProperties as? [String:AnyObject] else {return nil}
        guard let gifProperties = framePrpoerties[kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String] as? [String:AnyObject]
            else { return nil }

        // Use kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime or kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime
        if let delayTimeUnclampedProp = gifProperties[kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime as String] as? NSNumber {
            frameDuration = delayTimeUnclampedProp.floatValue
        } else {
            if let delayTimeProp = gifProperties[kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String] as? NSNumber {
                frameDuration = delayTimeProp.floatValue
            }
        }

        // Make sure its not too small
        if frameDuration < 0.011 {
            frameDuration = 0.100;
        }

        // Add frame to array of frames
        if let frame = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, i, nil) {
            tempTimesArray.append(NSNumber(value: frameDuration))
            framesArray.append(frame)
        }

        // Compile total loop time
        time = time + frameDuration
    }

    var timesArray = [NSNumber]()
    var base : Float = 0
    for duration in tempTimesArray {
        timesArray.append(NSNumber(value: base))
        base += ( duration.floatValue / time )
    }

    // From documentation of 'CAKeyframeAnimation':
    // the first value in the array must be 0.0 and the last value must be 1.0.
    // The array should have one more entry than appears in the values array.
    // For example, if there are two values, there should be three key times.
    timesArray.append(NSNumber(value: 1.0))

    // Create animation
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "contents")

    animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
    animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(time)
    animation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude;
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.values = framesArray
    animation.keyTimes = timesArray
    //animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete

    return animation;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by this:: createGIFAnimation?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, it is indeed an anchorpoint issue. Simply update the anchor point like so

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 900)
layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:1.0)
...
```